# Read values using Linq from nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dictionary

I have an object like

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> ColumnOverrides { get; set; }
```

Sample Data looks like

```
var ColumnOverrides = {
                Function: { hidden: true }
            }
```

I want to read the value of 'hidden' using linq. Please assist with the query.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use LINQ? `ColumnOverrides["Function"]["hidden"]` will give you a result of `"true"`.

Comment: @RustinCohle if you still want to use LINQ, `ColumnOverrides.First(co => co.Key == "Function").Value.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Key == "hidden").Value`

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. Pardon my nescience, is that C# code or js?

Comment: @tchelidze Thanks. Let me try.

Comment: It's C# - which is what I assumed you wanted, given that you were asking about LINQ...

Comment: Yes, I tried that, its awesome. But I want to do it dynamically, thats why I went for Linq. Still I could do this dynamically in this as well I guess.

Comment: @JonSkeet Assume the json is empty, in that case if I use ColumnOverrides["Function"]["hidden"], will it throw an exception? Should I check for null?

Comment: Yes, it will throw an exception - you'd need to use `TryGetValue` instead. At this point though, you should really just read tutorials or documentation for how to use `Dictionary<,>`.

Comment: Is there a way to check using TryGetValue for nested dictionary, straightaway?